# Why isn't the border prop working?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

## [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pryQe/)

Here's my html:

```
<span> Testing
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>One</td>
                <td>Two</td>
                <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</span>
```

And my css:

```
span {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Shouldn't the whole span get a normal border? I'm getting a messed up result in Firefox and Chrome (didn't test in others yet)

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: Because a span is an inline element.

Comment: Inline elements cannot contain block elements (`table`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<table>`s don't belong in `<span>`s, as `<table>`s are block-level elements and `<span>`s are inline elements, so there's no point testing that code as results will be unpredictable.

Use a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
span {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document. The best solution would be to modify the `<span>` and use a `<div>` instead.  A simple modification to reach your desired result.